# Авторизация прокси в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, proxy

В idea на windows при попытке настроить http прокси игнорируются указанные в настройках idea логин и пароль, используются данные текущей учётной записи. В idea в параметрах прокси можно указать правильные логин и пароль, пустые, неправильные. Результат один.

Как указать конкретные логин и пароль?
Так, что бы у прокси пользователя домен был отличным от домена текущего пользователя.

Например, одновременно с этим в eclipse всё работает прекрасно.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes=NTLM
```

в параметрах vm помогло.